# Where is the executable file of Windows Store application?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store

Where is the executable file of Windows Store application?

Is there any EXE file, associated with Windows Store?

Answer (score 5):

This is the store exe: C:\Windows\WinStore\WSHost.exe

Answer (score 4):

No there is not. [They are `.appx` files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx), which are really just zip files. However inside the `.appx` there is no exe either.

Comment: So, Store app is represented by `.appx` file then?

Comment: The application that runs the store is a exe, but programs that you download from the store are `.appx`

Answer (score 1):

I just had a quick look in the windows directory - C:\Windows\WinStore exists and there is an exe in there, but I am fairly sure the store is an appx style program, which shouldn't have an exe associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's here:

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.24.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WinStore.Mobile.exe

Comment: The location is going to be different for most people - the last bit of the folder name is randomly generated.

Comment: I think the down-vote for this answer is a bit unfair as @TorsoReaper did say, "_For **me** it's here_". Also, The folder name is not randomly generated, but actually dictated by the _current Windows update_. So the Store application directory should begin with "**C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_**".

Comment: this is for Windows 10, the question is tagged for Windows 8 and here the answer is wrong and useless

Answer (score -2):

Of course there is a process for this app... It's called WinStore.App.Exe

In case it's open and you wanna close it, all you have to do is: taskkill -f -im WinStore.App.Exe