# Store icon missing

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I have a Windows 8 machine I am trying to upgrade to Windows 8.1 but it's missing the Windows Store icon. Searching for "store" only brings up four or so icons for "Store documentation" and other related items, but not the actual Windows Store app icon.

How can I start the Windows Store when its icon is missing or how can I upgrade to Windows 8.1 without the Windows Store?

Comment: Not sure how to restore the shortcut but try the answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/681510/where-is-the-executable-file-of-windows-store-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the file **Windows Store.lnk** from `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-store-client-ui_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_1126a987ed3f98cb` to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. Now you should have the icon back.

Answer (score 1):

Trying magicandre1981's response, I note that `amd64_microsoft-windows-store-client-ui_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.16384_none_1126a987ed3f98cb` folder is missing on my pc.

I Suggest to:
1) Going in `C:\Windows\WinSxS`
2) Use the Search Tool on the upper-right side of the monitor, and filter the files by "windows-store-client-ui_31bf3856ad364e35"
3) Order results by last modified date
4) Open the first folder of the list
5) Copy the **Windows Store.lnk** to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: 6.2.9200 = WIn8, if you have 8.1, you must use 6.3.9600. I'm still using the original Win8, so it is 6.2.9200 for me.